# Ember's currentPath and currentRouteName are always undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

```
MyEmberApp.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.controllerFor('application').get('currentPath')); // Undefined.
    console.log(this.controllerFor('application').currentPath); // Undefined.
    // console.log(this.controller.currentRouteName); // Undefined.
    // console.log(Mars.__container__.lookup("controller:application").get("currentRouteName")); // Undefined.
    // console.log(this.controllerFor("application").get("currentPath")); // Undefined.
    // console.log(this.controllerFor("application").get("currentRouteName")); // Undefined.

    this.transitionTo(THE ROUTE NAME I FIND...);
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Even the official docs say I have to do it this way http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation fails to specify that you need to manually create this property on the `ApplicationController`.

```
MyEmberApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPath: 'test12'
});
```

Comment: how do I get it in an integration test?

Answer (score 0):

On beforeModel hook you dont have controller ready yet. Try to get on hook setupController.

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  debugger;
},
```